# javascript library based on jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins, javascript

What would be the advice on starting and organising a library of useful code based on the jquery library?

Im thinking of starting this for all of the code that I use alot and ends up just being copied and pasted between projects.

I would like to have all of this functionality included in some sort of library of plugins?

Any ideas or best practices in this area?

EDIT:
A lot of advice here is with regards to creating plugins - thats proving to be helpful.  Although, what i was really interested in is how to organise all of the plugins in one placce where i can simply call any piece of functionality whenever its required.

Comment: What would your library do? Maybe its functions fit the jQuery plugin format?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662555/is-it-a-good-idea-to-write-domain-specific-javascript-as-jquery-plugins

Comment: Im thinking of things like ajax shopping cart functionality, code for forms etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your library functions are completely dependent on jQuery (using either the `$.fn.myFunc`, for utility functions, or the `$.myFunc` style), then just implement your plugins as jQuery plugins. However, if you are just looking for a jQuery-like `$.fn.myFunc` framework, in which you only have utility functions, then just create your own namespace for your library functions like this:

```
MyNamespace = {};

MyNamespace.MyFunc = function(){


};
```

And then use your functions like this:

```
MyNamespace.MyFunc();
```

Comment: I have accepted your answer as it most cloesely answers my question, although I was hoping for some more advice from members on the code organisation aspect.  Thank you though.

Comment: Sure! As for code organization, I would suggest putting individual plugins (or groups of similar plugins) into separate files, like modules. In each module, you should create the `MyNamespace` namespace if it doesn't exist, like this: `MyNamespace = {};`. Then, you can safely include only the modules you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well, start here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking of this as a time-saver for your own uses, then it's a great idea. Every developer should take time to build up their own personal toolkit of functions / classes / plug-ins / etc that they use over and over.

If you're thinking of it as something to share with others, it may be a harder sell. You say you want to create a library of plug-ins, but in fact the jquery site already has such a library. Being hosted on the jquery site itself gives it a lot of credibility, so anyone searching for a plug-in would naturally gravitate towards it before looking anywhere else, which means that your third-party library would be somewhat overshadowed.

Comment: Hi, yes this is definately something to save me time as opposed to anything else external